# Strange Python Module issue, just on a mac

Tags: python, osx-lion

I have psutil installed, I can import it fine and use it to pull information, if I show all the modules, I can see it is installed.
However if I run the code below

```
try: 
  imp.find_module('psutil')
  pass
except ImportError:
  print 'This program needs psutil to work, as this is not installed the script will now exit'
  sys.exit()`
```

It says it's not installed.  I have this bit of code in a script and it works, on Windows, Solaris, Linux just not my Mac.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @MartijnPieters: He says it's installed and he can import it.

Comment: Also, the common pattern to test for a module, is to use `try: import psutil` - `except ImportError: # print message and exit`. Why use `imp` at all? And the `pass` statement is entirely redundant.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem on OS X 10.8, FWIW.

Comment: Yes it's installed, I can use it fine if I just say import psutil etc it works as it should

Comment: The pass is just there as this is the start of the code, so if it finds it the script continues

Comment: When you say you "just import" it, it works: How are you doing this import? That is, presumably you're at an interactive Python prompt, but how did you invoke Python? Next, how are you executing the code you've quoted above?

Comment: yes at an interactive Python prompt

Comment: Can I just ask so I know for next time, why was this question voted down??

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved the issue.  It's very strange, as I mentioned if I load python from the terminal, it loads the module and I can use it.  I can also see it if I see all the modules installed.

I done a search on the drive and I found psutil-1.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg, I have created a softlink to the file

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
sudo ln -s /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psutil-1.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg psutil.py
```

Once this was done, everything is working fine, I can still call it interactively but now the above snippet of code works

Thanks to everyone's help